# idapython: type information with different prefixes

Tags: ida, idapython

I checked how to get type information here - https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_typeinf.html

Although, I am not sure what these different type prefixes mean. For e.g. `BT_{type}`, `BTMT_{type}`, `BTF_{type}`, etc. I couldn't find any information which distinguishes these  types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeinf.hpp` is the most complex header file in the IDA SDK. Although it's reasonably well-designed once you understand how to use it, there is likely to be a lot of difficulty in your near future. You probably want to start by ignoring the part of the header that your question asks about, and instead look at the class `tinfo_t`, which is the primary data structure that IDA uses to represent types. From there, look at its member functions. For example, here are a number of member functions:

- `bool tinfo_t::is_ptr()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_array()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_func()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_complex()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_struct()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_union()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_udt()`
- `bool tinfo_t::is_enum()`

That should get you started. Good luck! You'll need it!

Comment: thanks so much for your comment, now I am using these functions for implementation. do you know the difference between decl_floating and floating?

Comment: I can't fully answer this, unfortunately. `tinfo_t` has a notion of a "declared type" (`decltype`) and a "real type" `realtype`). The `tinfo_t` holds the `decltype` inside of it, so doing things with it is very fast. As for the `realtype`, operations have to ask IDA about it, which is slower. Speed aside, the difference has something to do with `typedefs`, "type references", and "ordinals". For example, the declared type of a `typedef` is `BTF_TYPEDEF`, but if you want information about the type that the `typedef` refers to, you'll need to use the `realtype` functions. Sorry my answer is bad!

Comment: no, thanks so much for your answer! that really helps. I appreciate that